# I installed Django on my pc using pip install django

Tags: python, django

I installed Django in my pc using `pip install Django`.
but after some time I run the app but it is showing Django not install but Django is installed what is the problem ??

also, Django packages not showing or call.

Comment: Your pc is windows or Linux?

Comment: linux 18.04 ...

Comment: so, did you told your code to use that virtual env? if you are using pycharm. search for setting a virtual env in pycharm. I think Django installed, but your code could not found it.

Comment: Did you use sudo pip install Django to install django?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you probably installed Django inside a python virtual environment and are forgetting to turn it on back again to run the Django server.

You can activate the virtualenv you were using by typing:

```
source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
```

or if you are using virtualenvwrapper just type:

```
workon virtualenv_name
```

Alternatively you can check which packages are installed in your current environment using the command: `pip freeze` and search for Django in the ensuing installed packages list.